# Strange Behavior of Java Argument *

Tags: java

I wrote this class :

```
public class ListArg {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

javac ListArg.java // compiled class

I compiled above class and run like :
java ListArg *

But ListArg is displaying current directory contents on console and not "*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Looks like I was wrong and this might be Java doing it after all. If you're using a Unix shell, this is probably just the shell performing "globbing". However, it appears to do the same thing on Windows, which surprises me (as the Windows command line doesn't perform globbing by default).

Unfortunately, on Windows the normal quoting appears to give you a quoted argument, i.e. if you print `args[0]` having run

```
java ListArg '*'
```

it will *include* the single quote. I'm investigating whether there's a way of disabling this... although that would work on a Unix shell.

EDIT: Hmm... no luck so far in managing to have a string of *just* a star in Windows :(

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap * with quotes:
`java ListArg '*'` or `java ListArg "*"`

Answer (score 1):

This is your shell (unless you are on Windows) expanding *. Try escaping it by putting it in quotes such as "*".

For me on Windows XP using double quotes works, "*" as argument gives the java program * as argument (no double quotes and no expansion). Maybe this is different for other Window versions.

Comment: Unfortunately `\*` on Windows lists all the files in the root directory :(

Comment: @JonSkeet I should have remembered. Unpacked an old Windows machine to actually test on. On that "*" (double quotes) works. No doubt you have a newer Windows available to test on.

Answer (score 1):

you give command line arguments in double quotes and check.

Comment: in windows even without double quotes also it works.but if you give in single quotes,single quotes also will be printed.ex:if you give java ListArg 'john',it gives you 'john' as output

Answer (score 0):

`*` is `wildcard` character which is preprocessed by terminal

Similar to `*` ,you can use

- `*.*`
- `*.txt` .This will list files and folders with .txt as end

and etc,You can try that

This [link](http://stillstup.blogspot.com/2008/10/terminal-wildcards.html) provides information on these.

It is not only working in Linux,but also in Windows.